# "ReferenceError: document is not defined" when testing in-browser with mocha webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I'm using webdriver with mocha.  When I try to use "document.getElementById" I end up getting "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

I'm testing in-browser (not headless).

Any info I've found seems to indicate that issue happens when testing headlessly (ie. in Node) and requires jsdom-global.  I tried installing that just to see what happens.  It got rid of the "ReferenceError: document is not defined" error, but "document.getElementById" would end up as undefined (which makes sense since I'm testing in-browser)

Am I correct that while testing in-browser I "should" be able to use "document.getElementById"?

Thanks

Note: This is just for one special case.  I'm aware this not standard use.

Comment: Mocha does some weird stuff with the globals, you can set them up with the [`globals`](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#globals) function on the `mocha` object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use browser calls instead of webdriver's methods you need to use [executeScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#executeScript).

In your case, it would be something like this, considering you would receive the id as a parameter:

```
driver.executeScript(`document.getElementById("${elementId}")`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to automate using selenium for browser testing, you should not be using document.getElementById.

Locates elements by the ID attribute. This locator uses the CSS selector *[id="$ID"], not document.getElementById.
See more here
[https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_By.html]

(Updated Assuming you are doing browser test Here is full example with Mocha with use of id :

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

async function test() {
  var driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer()
    .withCapabilities({ browserName: 'chrome' })
    .build();

  await driver.get('http://www.google.com');

  let searchField = await driver.findElement(By.id('lst-ib'));
  searchField.sendKeys('webdriver');
}

describe('Describe test', function() {
  this.timeout(50000);
  it('Some test', function(done) {
    test().then(function() {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I guess I should have mentioned that I know "document.getElementById" is not standard for selenium.  I just need to use it for one special case.  Thanks again